# cannot use subquery in trigger WHEN condition postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I want to use subquery in postgresql 9.2.4 WHEN clause.
it complained that I can't use subquery in trigger WHEN condition.

Here's my code

```
CREATE TRIGGER BeerTrig
AFTER INSERT ON Sells
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.beer NOT IN (SELECT name FROM Beers))
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertNewBeer();
```

is there a workaround how to make subquery in when clause?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could call insertNewBeer() always and decide there whether to actually insert a row or not.

Answer (score 0):

yeah been looking at this for a while. Looks like in postgres, we can only have simple checks in when using NEW and OLD but we cannot run a subquery inside when. In those cases, you will always have to call the function and run the query there.